# Is there a way to avoid superfluous space changes in git history?

Tags: javascript, git, eslint, git-diff

If one has made a minor mistake to formatting, say indenting a line that does not need to be indented, is there a way to not have this in the commit history.

For example using git diff I can see ...

```
-  const getUniqueUserID = require('./websocket-user-id');
+const getUniqueUserID = require('./websocket-user-id');
```

which might be annoying to see in the commit history.  Is this indeed just a change of 2 spaces, the formatting is hard to read.

Should I just commit this space fix with another more substantial fix?

Comment: auto format on save and pre commit hooks can also help with this kind of thing not happening.

Comment: I use eslint --fix from time to time, but I have to do it manually.  Actually this is a one off case as eslint syntax checks me as I type as well.  Really odd, this got in.  I'm just going to commit it.

Answer (score 4):

Are you concerned about there being an extra commit, or are you concerned with the diff being less useful?

You can use [`-b` and `-w` (`--ignore-space-change` and `--ignore-all-space`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-options#Documentation/diff-options.txt--b) to minimize the diff, but a commit is a commit and if it's a part of the history it would be more confusing to hide it.

I tend to think it's not a big deal to make a small well-described change, even if it's whitespace-only.